# Identificar todos os links de um site e alterar ele com java script

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tem como criar um script, pra identificar todos os links de um site e modificar eles depois, ou seja adiciono o código no footer.php e assim ele mudar os links. Seria assim:

**LINK ANTIGO**: https://site.com/dwd8464

**MUDAR AUTOMATICAMENTE PARA**: https://site.com/linkdireto/?a=dwd8464

Tem como fazer ? como se fosse um protetor de link, porem para mudar o link.

*Com o código no rodapé do site, ele identifica todos, sempre precisar modificar as postagens do meu site.*

**Seria como aqueles scripts que o adfly usa pra identificar links, e adicionar o protetor de links deles.**

Comment: Se você vai ter todo esse trabalho em um site cujo PHP você tem acesso, já não seria melhor mudar no próprio PHP?

Comment: Você até poderia enxertar um JavaScript para percorrer todos os elementos `<a>` e fazer essa alteração, mas isso prejudicaria a experiência do usuário (sem falar que poderia abrir uma pequena brecha para clicar no link antigo)

Comment: os links são usados em outros sites, ai quero disponibilizar os javascript, para poderem colocar no sites deles, para poder mudar meus linsks, para o novo formato, assim sem precisar modificar cada postagem..

Comment: você quer mudar o link que terceiros apontam pra você?

Comment: Sim, eles usam meu servidor. Ai eles querem mudar o parâmetro de url, para a nova sem precisar modificar manualmente.

Comment: Acredito que alterar o `.htaccess` seja a melhor solução nesse caso, mas sinceramente um `Ctrl + H` em uma IDE meia boca é bem simples de fazer do que um javascript que faça isso

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam ou usar um `sed` para fazer edição programática de texto...

Comment: Ai e que ta pessoal, /linkdireto/ e uma pasta que eu mesmo fiz, e n posso mexer em .htacsess, por que vai ser em sites de clientes, e quase igual aqueles scripts que o adfly disponibiliza.

Comment: se eu entendi, `/linkdireto/` é uma pasta no seu servidor onde tem algo que você disponibiliza a seus clientes, você pode alterar **O SEU `.htacces`** para redirecionar os links no formato antigo para o novo, mas, se você for disponibilizar o js, disponibilize uma regex que capture os links antigos e troque por novos e diga a seu cliente para usar ele num netbeans, vs code, acho que até no sublime da pra fazer isso

Comment: Ai e que ta, os links antigos ainda vão funcionar! o redirecionamento quero fazer so pra quem usar o script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, fiz um código simples com javascript. Estou pegando todos os elementos ***"a"***, pegando seus links, cortando eles e concatenando com o ***"/seulink/"***

Embora eu tenha feito pegando os elementos ***"a"*** recomendo colocar uma ***class*** nesses elementos, para que não sejam pegos todos da página.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
      <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
      <a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309522/identificar-todos-os-links-de-um-site-e-alterar-ele-com-java-script">Sua Pergunta</a>
      <p>Clique no botão para alterar os links</p>
    
      <button onclick="mudar()">Clique!</button>
      <script>
        function mudar() {
          var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
          var qntElementos = elemento.length;
          for (i = 0; i < qntElementos; i++) {
            var link = elemento[i].href;
            var cortaLink = link.split(".com/");
            var novoLink = cortaLink[0] + '.com/SEULINK/' + cortaLink[1];
            elemento[i].href = novoLink;
          }
        }
      </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```